# Return multiple attributes with perl's xpath command

Tags: xml, perl, bash, xpath

I'm trying to use the xpath command on my mac to return some attribute data from an xml document without writing a script for it. Documents have the following node:

```
<BaseTable id="32821" name="Web Service Send Log">
```

I would like to return the `name` and `id` attributes for the nodes.

I'm able to get each with the following commands:

```
$ xpath FileName.xml //BaseTable/@id
$ xpath FileName.xml //BaseTable/@name
```

But when I try to return both attributes I get an error saying that the parens are junk:

```
$ xpath FileName.xml //BaseTable/(@id|@name)
```

I've searched around and not found the correct syntax and the `xpath` command doesn't have an associated manual file.

Is this possible to do this directly from the command line and if so, how would the syntax look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(@id|@name)` is XPath 2.0 syntax, while Perl `xpath` uses 1.0. Here's an alternative:

```
xpath -e '//BaseTable/@*[name()="id" or name() = "name"]' FileName.xml
```

Comment: I tried this out and it still says that there's junk after the `@` symbol. Actually, the xpath command that I have says says (when I type in just `xpath`) that the syntax of the command must be `xpath fileName pattern`. I think my mac has an odd version of the xpath command. I'm going to look around for a different version.